# How to sort all chinese references before English ones

Tags: biblatex, sorting, cjk

I'm writing my phd thesis, which is in Chinese. 
It's required to sort the all Chinese references before English ones in the Section of reference.

However, it seems that there is not any existing sorting options that can support this.

I tried to use `\usepackage[backend = biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=nty]{biblatex}`. All Chinese references were listed behind English ones.

Is there any way that can sort all the Chinese references before all the English ones?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You should specify a a `sortkey` for each of the Chinese references so they are placed before the English ones. You may have to sort them manually, but this would only have to happen once.

Comment: It could be interesting to see whether a custom sorting scheme with the `language` field before `sortname` would do the trick. (You'd need the `language` field present in the entries of course, but that is the same amount of work as adding `presort`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use the `presort` field.  Unlike `sortkey`, `presort` would be able to sort into broad categories, leaving the sorting within the categories to `biblatex`, instead of having to sort every entry individually (as with `sortorder`).

`biblatex.def` defines the `nyt` sorting style as:

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{nyt}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  ......
```

So, by adding a `presort = 1` for all Chinese entries in your `.bib` file and a `presort = 2` for all English entries, they will be sorted by language first, then proceed to be sorted by the regular `nyt`/name,year,title scheme after that as usual.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution might be the following:
- edit your *.bbl file
- mark and cut all english entries
- paste them after the chinese entries
- save this file as your new *.bbl
- and run xelarex (or ist lua?) again.